# Queue PNR returns "NO PNR IN AAA" (QueuePlaceLLSRQ)

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I am trying to Queue PNR with ["Place Queue Message (QueuePlaceLLSRQ)"](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/queue/Place_Queue_Message) API.
So, I follow these steps to Queue PNR.

Step 1 - Create Session (SessionCreateRQ)

Step 2 - Retrieve Itinerary (GetReservationRQ)

Step 3 - Queue PNR (QueuePlaceLLSRQ)

And I am stuck at step number 3, it always return an error message - `NO PNR IN AAA`

What is this actually mean and how can I avoid this error?

---

Below are the request and response payload data

### Request data

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>webservices.sabre.com</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId></CPAId>
            <ConversationId>convid</ConversationId>
            <Service>QueuePlaceLLSRQ</Service>
            <Action>QueuePlaceLLSRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>convid112</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2020-04-20T09:25:27Z</Timestamp>
                <TimeToLive>2020-04-20T09:25:27Z</TimeToLive>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="Base64Binary" valueType="String" >Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1587564276872!533!5</BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <QueuePlaceRQ Version="2.0.4" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <QueueInfo>
                <QueueIdentifier Number="22" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" PseudoCityCode="****"/>
            </QueueInfo>
        </QueuePlaceRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

### Response Data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:ConversationId>convid</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>QueuePlaceLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>QueuePlaceLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1815326504754440150</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2020-04-22T14:01:16</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>convid</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1587564074215!6005!9</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <QueuePlaceRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.4">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2020-04-22T09:01:16-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>NO PNR IN AAA</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </QueuePlaceRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are either calling `GetReservation` with `Stateless` instead of `Stateful`, so the reservation is not on the work area when the queue place is attempted, or using a different session.

If that is the only thing that you are doing to the reservation, you can add UniqueId and place it in that queue without even retrieving it.
`<UniqueID ID="ABC123"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question since I was in the wrong workflow and I hope it will help someone too.

In Sabre's product catalog, there is no **Queue Place API** for REST, it's only for **SOAP**.

And the problem was that I was using **REST** for the first steps such as `Bargain Finder Max` and `Create Passenger Name Record`. After that, I tried to use the [`Queue Place API`](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/queue/Place_Queue_Message) in **SOAP** and the system probably didn't notice the PNR.

Actually, the **Queue Place API** is available in REST but it has to be sent with [`Create Passenger Name Record API`](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/reference-documentation) and must append an object `QueueInfo` under `PostProcessing` as below.

```js
    "PostProcessing": {
                  "QueuePlace":{
                      "QueueInfo":{

                         "QueueIdentifier":[
                            {
                              "Number":"123",
                              "PrefatoryInstructionCode":"11",
                              "PseudoCityCode":"****"
                            }
                          ]
                      }
                  }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

In all probability, the PNR is not available in the work area. That is why it is saying no PNR. GetReservation has a request type parameter. It can be set to:
Stateless
Trip
Stateful
Stateful requests refers to PNRs that have not been committed; therefore, the PNR Locator cannot be mandatory. Stateless/Trip request refers to PNRs that have been committed and stored in the database. This request type requires the PNR Locator.

Please check if you are calling GetReservation with Stateless instead of Stateful, so the reservation is not on the work area when the queue place is attempted, or using a different session. You must have a PNR in your work area.